# Cross Account Access in Lakeformation is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lake-formation

I'm trying to give cross-account access to a database. When I'm doing so it is not working. It shows something like this:[image]

It was working fine before but right now it is showing the above status. I'm using the Cross Account Version settings version 4 and have un checked the 2 options available at the start in Data Catalog Settings. I have registered the s3 location of the tables/database in the data lake locations. I checked in Resource Access Manager and it shows that 0 resources were shared with the account I'm trying to share to. Im having Administrator Access in both the accounts.